# Sencha Touch 2 redirectTo method used to send data to another controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch 2, on a controller, I have the following code:

```
onRedirectToCartCommand: function(view, shoppingCartData) {
        console.log('ProductViewController - onRedirectToCartCommand()');
        console.log(shoppingCartData)
        this.redirectTo('cart');
    }
```

Upon triggering an event, I use the **redirectTo** function, which tells Sencha's router to create a new view and add it into the **viewport**.

Do you know a way to send an object along with the **redirectTo** function over to the router (which is another controller which handles the site-s routes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take an object from one place to another you have a couple possibilities :

- Call a function of the destination, with your object in argument

The most obvious answer, usefull when you want to create a flow, and if that object is just necessary in these two places.

- Store your object in a static place (either a `singleton`, or a `static` field of a class)

Good for storing stuff you'll be likely using several times in different places. Just create a class with the `singleton` property, and put objects in it as if they where fields (`MySingleton.set('objectName', object)`).

- Local Storage

You can use the HTML 5 Api `local storage` (sencha has a way to do it easily) and store your object in the local cache of the device. It's good for things that needs to stay (like a session).

Then you just have to retrieve the object from either the function, the singleton class, or the local storage.